# Copy Excel Row if Cell is equal to specific values

Tags: vba

I have data from A2 to K100. How can I have VBA copy the entire row (A to K) when the values in Col K is 1 or 2. To paste in another sheet as values. "no error msg required"

### Thanks

[I'm finally going for the below in the destination sheet. However, how can I resolve the issue with **Range("A16").select**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvM8q.png)

```
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List of attendees").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List of attendees").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
Key:=Range("H1:H300"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List of attendees").AutoFilter.Sort
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$300").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="="
Range("A16").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("D1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
```

Comment: `Range.AutoFilter` or `Range.AdvancedFilter` maybe.

Comment: Thanks, I'll study that path @BigBen

Comment: I'm finally going for the below in the destination sheet. However, how can I make